# Redirected to main page when trying to parse html with python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, scraper

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.csgolounge.com/api/mathes"
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

print (data)
```

I am trying to use this code to get the text from [this page](https://csgolounge.com/api/matches), but every time I try to scrape or get the text from the page, I am redirected to home page, and my code outputs the html from the homepage. The page I am trying to scrape is a .php file, and not an html or textfile. I would like to get the text from the page and then extract the data and do what I want with it.

I have tried changing the headers of my code, that the website would think that I am not a bot, but a chrome browser, but I still get redirected to the homepage. I have tried using diffrent html python parsers like BeautifulSoup, and the python built in class, as well as many other popular parsers, but they all give the same result.

Is there a way to stop this, and to get the text from this link? Is it a mistake in my code or what?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try it without the "www" part.
Rewrite `http://www.csgolounge.com/api/mathes` as `https://csgolounge.com/api/mathes`

If it doesn't work, try Selenium.

It may be getting stuck since it can't process the javascript part.
Selenium can handle it better.